# Facebook registration/login plugins

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to update my site so that it can be linked to facebook users. I have a database and use mysql for the original login system. I now want to replace that with facebook. Thing is i want to still run my checks, i dont just want any facebook user to log in, only ones that get entered into the database. The only way users can access to my site is with a .edu address. How would i incorporate this along with the facebook plugins? Facebook has two options for the login-sytem, JAVASCRIPT or Server-side scripting. I just want to know the best practical way of doing what i want to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a 2-step login process then. First, validate the user's address (.edu or not), then Login with facebook. Not a good design, but both needs to be separated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following step will be helpful to you

1. Go for Login With Facebook
2. Take Extended Permission from User (email,read_stream).
3. Once you get Permission from user get user's facebook id using **getSignedRequest()** or **FB.getLoginStatus**.
4. Get user's information using graph api (i.e. https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor)
5. Get email id from response and check for valid user email (.edu).
6. If email Id is not .edu (Destroy user session and show invalid message)